# Syntax for Realtime Database in Firebase not working?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use the Realtime Database to store data. I already set up the SDK in the HTML. But my code doesn't seem to working when I try to use .push().

```
    var name = $("#flname").val();
    var email = $("#orderemail").val();

    var Firebase = new Firebase("https://wexpress-5a322.firebaseio.com/");
    Firebase.push({
    name: name,
    email: email
    })
```

Can someone help troubleshoot my code and help me out?

Comment: what firebase version are you using? What errors are you facing?

Comment: @adolfosrs Thanks for the response! I'm using the version 3.0.2 . And when I try to push my data to the database, I don't see any data logged in the Realtime Database

Comment: is there any error in your logs?